# gdb breakpoint gets hit in the wrong line number

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb

In gdb, I set a breakpoint to make gdb stop when the first `if` condition is met. But gdb stops in another line and `if` condition isn't met. I've read [gdb breakpoint does not get hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550558/gdb-breakpoint-does-not-get-hit), but it's stll not solved. I think gdb stops only when `if (a == 1)` is met and just in line 3282. Am I wrong?

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize("O0")

static void __attribute__ ((noinline)) search(int a, int b) 
{  
    // other code here 

    if (a == 1) {
        printf("condition1\n"); 
        printf("condition1\n"); // line 3282, breakpoint is set here   
    }
    if (b == 1) {              // line 3284,  in fact, gdb stops in this line    
        printf("condition2\n");
        printf("condition2\n");
    }
}
#pragma GCC pop_options
```

set breakpoint in line 3282 using command `b file.c:3282`

> Breakpoint 1 at 0x40da02: file file.c, line
>   3282.

`info breakpoint` shows:

> Num     Type           Disp Enb Address What
>  
>   1       breakpoint   keep y   0x000000000040da02 in
>   search at file.c:3282
>           breakpoint already hit 1 time

But gdb stops in **line 3284, instead of 3282, and a is not equal 1**

> [Switching to Thread 0x7ffff75b8700 (LWP 3631)] 
> Breakpoint 1, search
>   at file.c:3284
>  3284              if (b == 1) {

gcc --version

> gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Comment: Have you considered that `A` is just never greater than 1?

Comment: No, gdb just print "hello".

Comment: And how does that disprove what I said? It's supposed to print `"correct"`

Comment: Many times I debug the project, If I set breakpoint at line 3000, gdb just stops near 3000. gdb even jumps back to front lines when executing `n` command.  I think it's gcc optimisation. Only `a>1` can "correct" be printed. If I don't change compiling script, Can I make gdb just stop at the specific line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent gcc optimizing some statements in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219829/how-to-prevent-gcc-optimizing-some-statements-in-c)

Comment: It's probably best to add `__attribute__((optimize("O0")))` to the function definition.  Or if your script has a way of doing a non-optimized build, you can do that instead.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying `__attribute__((optimize("O0")))`. I just want gdb to stop at specific line.

Comment: @jszakmeister It still doesn't hit the breakpoint.

Comment: @user7328234 You might try `__attribute__ ((noinline))` as well.  But without more context, it's really difficult to help you here.

Comment: @user7328234 there are many ways to do it, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4326414/72178.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set breakpoint in C or C++ code programmatically for gdb on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326414/set-breakpoint-in-c-or-c-code-programmatically-for-gdb-on-linux)

Comment: @jszakmeister I've tried to describe the problem I meet clearly. But I don't know whether it's more clear.

Comment: Post a minimal complete example + compiler flags so we can try to reproduce the problem ....

Comment: @Karoly Horvath I'm learning source code [nDPI](https://github.com/ntop/nDPI), a tool for traffic classfy. But when I add code in ndpi_main.c and debug nDPI , gdb doesn't stop in the right line. I do think it's more complicated to refer to nDPI, so I just point out the specific problem.

Comment: @user7328234: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: related: [GCC option that can cause trouble when debugging with GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2246204/11107541)

Answer (score 6):

I change `gcc -g -O2` to `gcc -g -O0`, then everything goes well. Following is document about `-O2` option of gcc command.

> -O2 Optimize even more.  GCC performs nearly all supported optimizations that do not involve a space-speed tradeoff.
>              As compared to -O, this option increases both compilation time and the performance of the generated code.

Comment: For FORTRAN,  I tried `ifort -g -O0 -u -c -o levelAS.o levelAS.f` followed by `ifort -g -O0 -u  levelAS.o -o level.x`, but the line numbers still don't match.