# Breakpoint in C++ set at wrong line in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging

My question is basically same with [breakpoint wrong place - vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765353/visual-studio-code-breakpoint-appearing-in-wrong-place) question. But it occurs in c++.

When I set line breakpoint by clicking gutters, the breakpoint is created in wrong line. For example, I clicked on line 28 but the breakpoint is created on line 34 (both visually and debugger stopping). 
While setting breakpoints on some lines works correctly, the majority seem to jump to an incorrect line.

Below is log from engine logging.

```
1: (41828) <-1052-break-insert -f B_Not_Quite_Latin_Square.cpp:28
1: (41837) ->1052^done,bkpt={number="12",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x00007ff6e0de1880",
    func="std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char)",
    file="C:\\Data\\CompetitiveProgramming\\B_Not_Quite_Latin_Square.cpp",
    fullname="C:\\Data\\CompetitiveProgramming\\B_Not_Quite_Latin_Square.cpp",
    line="34",thread-groups=["i1"],times="0",original-location="B_Not_Quite_Latin_Square.cpp:28"
```

I have clicked line 28 for breakpoint. However in the last line of log, the debugger returns inserted breakpoint in line="34".

Here are my tasks.json and launch.json configurations.
tasks.json:

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build",
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "command": "C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
      "args": [
        "-x",
        "c++",
        "-g",
        "-O2",
        "-std=gnu++20",
        "-static",
        "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Debug",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "logging": {"engineLogging":true},
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
          "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
          "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Trial

I have tried adding `sourceFileMap` to launch.json. However the problem didn't go away.

```
"sourceFileMap":{
  "${fileDirname}": {
    "editorPath": "${fileDirname}",
    "useForBreakpoints": true
  }
},
```

Comment: What is this "engine log", and what does it do? Where does it come from? What program creates this log? What happens on "line 28"? What happens on "line 34"?

Comment: As for the "jump" itself, perhaps the compiler just optimized away some of the code?

Comment: Try removing `-O2`. And even without optimization, if there's nothing going on on a specific line, the breakpoint will be moved to the next meaningful line.

Comment: Generally, debuggers have best chances of keeping track of code lines when stepping through a program if compilation is done WITHOUT optimisation (which can, effectively, re-order and even remove lines of code entirely) and WITH debugging symbols included.       You have the `-g` option which enables debugging symbols, but `-O2` to enable (a level of) optimisation.   Remove the `-O2`.

Comment: Thank you all for leaving comments. Removing `-O2` solved this issue. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I can't close vote anymore, but if I could, I'd dupe hammer this to https://stackoverflow.com/q/15550558/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2246204/11107541, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/41565105/11107541. if someone else could close vote to one of those, that'd be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `-O2` option from build task solved this issue.

This question was related to gdb, not vscode integrated debugger. 
There exists other SO answers about this problem. 
[GCC option that can cause trouble when debugging with GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246204/gcc-option-that-can-cause-trouble-when-debugging-with-gdb) 
[gdb breakpoint gets hit in the wrong line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41565105/gdb-breakpoint-gets-hit-in-the-wrong-line-number)

Comment: you should close as duplicate instead of answering. under your question, flick flag -> needs improvement -> duplicate